# Detect Final Layout Size for View with Flexible Width in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout

I am using size classes in an iOS 8-only app and I have a view inside a `UITableViewCell` that has a flexible width. Its auto layout constraints are defined as follows:

[image]

As you can see, its width varies depending on the device width/orientation.

When I print its frame in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I see **(180.0, 10.0, 400.0, 60.0)** which shows a **400 width**. But when I measure the view in the simulator, it is only **175 wide**, which is reinforced by the fact that my view's content is truncated (I'm drawing some stuff inside it).

How can I know when the `UITableViewCell`'s contraints and subviews are completely done rendering so that I can redraw stuff inside my view?

**Update**

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I'm doing the following to get the cell:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TimeTypeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimeTypeCell

let customField = customFields[indexPath.row]

cell.fieldNameLabel.text = customField["name"] as? String
cell.fieldValueLabel.text = customField["total"] as? String
cell.graphData = customField["totalGraph"] as! [Double]

cell.fieldGraph.dataSource = cell.self
cell.fieldGraph.delegate = cell.self

cell.fieldGraph.reloadData() //This is where the redrawing happens
```

Comment: Try viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: As I understand it, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is a method of `UITableViewController`. Is there something equivalent for `UITableViewCell`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Call `cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()` to get the content views laid out correctly. While the cell itself should be the correct size when returned from `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_, forIndexPath:)`, it seems that the content view doesn't immediately run layout, so you need to call it manually if you need it up to date at that point.

Comment: Thanks!!!! Great answer! I called this from 
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: I'm voting this down for now as it does not seem to work.

Comment: This is it! And it does still work as of Xcode 9.4.1 in 2018.

Comment: Worked for me today. 5 April 2019

Answer (score 16):

I ended up with overriding `UITableViewCell.layoutSubviews` method:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self.contentView layoutSubviews]; // this does the trick
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to either check for the width in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

If you put `println(self.tableView.frame.width)` into `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` you'll be able to see the width as each method is called.

Comment: I can see the width of the table, and the view in question shows the right width after a few calls to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, but my issue remains in that I need to know when the layout rendering is complete so I can trigger a redraw in my view.